# Total datediff number of days in split daterange not equal to datediff number of days in non-split daterange, why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can some sharp mind point to why these two queries don't give the same amount of total days - and what should be done to always get the correct total of days when rolling up into one row.

[image]

```
SELECT
[Year1_2_3] = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-08-20', '2019-08-19')

SELECT
   [Year1_2_3_Sum] = [Q].[Year1] + [Q].[Year2] + [Q].[Year3]
 , [Year1]         = [Q].[Year1]
 , [Year2]         = [Q].[Year2]
 , [Year3]         = [Q].[Year3]
FROM
   (
   SELECT
   [Year1] = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-08-20', '2017-08-19')
 , [Year2] = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2017-08-20', '2018-08-19')
 , [Year3] = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-08-20', '2019-08-19')
   ) [Q]
```

---

```
    SELECT
   [Order_Year1_2_3]            = [Q].[Order_Year1_2_3]
 , [Order_Amount]               = [Q].[Order_Amount]
 , [Order_AmountPerDay]         = [Q].[Order_AmountPerDay]
 , [OrderLine_Year1_Days]       = [Q].[OrderLine_Year1_Days]
 , [OrderLine_Year2_Days]       = [Q].[OrderLine_Year2_Days]
 , [OrderLine_Year3_Days]       = [Q].[OrderLine_Year3_Days]
 , [OrderLine_Year1_Amount]     = [Q].[Order_AmountPerDay] * [Q].[OrderLine_Year1_Days]
 , [OrderLine_Year2_Amount]     = [Q].[Order_AmountPerDay] * [Q].[OrderLine_Year2_Days]
 , [OrderLine_Year3_Amount]     = [Q].[Order_AmountPerDay] * [Q].[OrderLine_Year3_Days]
 , [OrderLine_Year1_2_3_Amount] = ([Q].[Order_AmountPerDay] * [Q].[OrderLine_Year1_Days]) + ([Q].[Order_AmountPerDay] * [Q].[OrderLine_Year2_Days]) + ([Q].[Order_AmountPerDay] * [Q].[OrderLine_Year3_Days])
FROM
   (
   SELECT
   [Order_Year1_2_3]      = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-08-20', '2019-07-19')
 , [Order_Amount]         = 145000.00
 , [Order_AmountPerDay]   = CONVERT(FLOAT, 145000) / CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-08-20', '2019-07-19'))
 , [OrderLine_Year1_Days] = CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-08-20', '2017-08-19'))
 , [OrderLine_Year2_Days] = CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEDIFF(DAY, '2017-08-20', '2018-08-19'))
 , [OrderLine_Year3_Days] = CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-08-20', '2019-07-19'))
   ) [Q]
```

I added a second query here with a better example - and an amount measure for illustration. I need to preserve the correct from/to dates for each year (this would actually be three separate lines with respective from/to dates) , but still be able to roll up into the "header" level and get a correct setup.

Comment: Because the `datediff` function counts day transitions, and in your Year1_2_3 query you will get 2 more transitions as you move from 1 year to the next, which are not included when you sum then individually.

Comment: You get to define what is *correct*, which one suits your business needs?

Comment: I have an order total that I split into X years. Then I'd like to split the amount correctly for each line using the number of days for each line. But each line will not always be a full year. I'll prep a small example, sec..

Comment: "as you move from 1 year to the next" made me think. I should add one more day for each "line" except the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATEDIFF(day, ...)` returns the number of midnights between the given dates.

For example, `DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-08-20', '2016-08-21')` returns 1.

If you think of `[2016-08-20 -- 2016-08-21]` as a closed-closed interval, which includes both dates, then it is two days.

Usually, it is easier to deal with intervals when you treat them as closed-open intervals. In this approach you would have `[2016-08-20 -- 2016-08-22)` to define the same two-day interval.

I would recommend to adopt this approach and always treat the starting date/time of the interval as inclusive and end date/time of the interval as exclusive. This convention would naturally work correctly for intervals that have time component as well. For example, `[2016-08-20T00:00:00 -- 2016-08-22T00:00:00)` clearly says that interval is two full days, 48 hours.

Your example would look like this:

```
SELECT
[Year1_2_3] = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-08-20', '2019-08-20')

SELECT
   [Year1_2_3_Sum] = [Q].[Year1] + [Q].[Year2] + [Q].[Year3]
 , [Year1]         = [Q].[Year1]
 , [Year2]         = [Q].[Year2]
 , [Year3]         = [Q].[Year3]
FROM
   (
   SELECT
   [Year1] = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-08-20', '2017-08-20')
 , [Year2] = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2017-08-20', '2018-08-20')
 , [Year3] = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-08-20', '2019-08-20')
   ) [Q]
```

**Result**

```
+-----------+
| Year1_2_3 |
+-----------+
|      1095 |
+-----------+

+---------------+-------+-------+-------+
| Year1_2_3_Sum | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 |
+---------------+-------+-------+-------+
|          1095 |   365 |   365 |   365 |
+---------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

---

Also, have a look at article [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) by Aaron Bertrand. He shows there several examples of how adopting [closed; open) intervals for date/time ranges is often better.

---

If your end users are interpreting date range as [inclusive; inclusive], then adjust the end date by 1 day **during the presentation to the user**, at the very last moment when you want to show the result to the user, but internally in the database and code always work with [closed; open) intervals.

Comment: Nice article! Thanks